# Is async.js needed to process multiple ffmpeg conversions at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, async.js

I'm trying to convert youtube videos to mp3 via my Node.js server, using 'ytdl-core' and 'fluent-ffmpeg'. Since the server is intended to process multiple requests at the same time, it got me thinking whether or not async.js is needed to convert videos in a time efficient manner.

The interesting thing however, is that upon testing the handling of multiple requests with and without using async.js, the result seems to be the same both ways - the time it takes to convert 3 videos is the same.

Here is the code I'm using without async.js:

```
server.get('/download/:id', (req, res) => {

  const id = req.params.id;
  let stream = ytdl(`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${id}`);

  ffmpeg(stream)
    .audioCodec('libmp3lame')
    .audioBitrate(128)
    .toFormat('mp3')
    .save(`public/downloads/${id}.mp3`)
    .on('error', err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      console.log('file downloaded');
      send(req, `public/downloads/${id}.mp3`).pipe(res);
    });
});
```

And this is the code using async.js:

```
let queue = async.queue((task, callback) => {
  let stream = ytdl(`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${task.id}`);

  ffmpeg(stream)
  .audioCodec('libmp3lame')
  .audioBitrate(128)
  .toFormat('mp3')
  .save(`public/downloads/${task.id}.mp3`)
  .on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
    callback(err)
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    send(task.req, `public/downloads/${task.id}.mp3`).pipe(task.res);
    callback('file sucessfully downloaded');
  });
}, 5);

queue.drain = function() {
  console.log('all items downloaded');
}

server.get('/download/:id', (req, res) => {
  queue.push({req: req, id: req.params.id, res: res}, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas why both methods seem to finish conversion at roughly the same time? I would imagine using async.js should finish converting the videos faster due to processing in parallel, but that isn't the case.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: asynchronous is not the same as parallel

Comment: thank you for the hint! I did some reading on the difference between the two and if I understand correctly the ffmpeg conversion happens on the CPU and javascript is single-threaded. This means that there will only ever be one conversion happening at a time using my current setup. Am I right in thinking like this?

Reading up on this, I have trouble understanding what purpose the async queue has at all. Node handles multiple requests "asynchronously" by default, so what's the point of the async module?

Comment: looking at async package, it seems that queue makes pool (not worker pool but pool of async processes that can be limited in terms of concurency). They use "parallel" for argument, but it looks only confusing. I did not see any use of process.spawn in that package. Actually you can try to use process.spawn inside async.queue and use it like worker pool to limit processes..

Comment: also make sure that your ydl downloads only audio stream if possible and not whole video..

Comment: I think you're right, using the queue really only makes sense when trying to limit the amount of async operations (or processes if I were to use workers, but I don't think I'll go with that). Since I currently want to have as many asynchronous conversions happening I'm fine with using Node as it is. I will also make sure to only download the audio stream - I left it as an mp4 stream for testing purposes but forgot to switch to audioonly after.

Thanks very much for your help!